# AWS SES SMTP- error 554 after switching to new server (and IP). NOT IN sandbox mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm having an issue with AWS SES after switching to a new server. I've been using the service (SES) for a few years and everything was fine - I'm not in a sandbox mode. But just recently I switched to a new server and problems began.
I'm getting these types of errors when I'm trying to send a new email:

```
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
email_address_here@email.com


Reporting-MTA: dns; a7-18.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822; email_address_here@email.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes. 
<450 4.1.8 <01020183adb179f8-ecc0a1d6-ce0f-42bc-a892-2ec5582748ce-000000@support.mydomain.com>:

Sender address rejected: Domain not found>
Status: 4.4.7
```

My SES account has DKIM verification & custom email verification. Do I need to do everything all over again in order to fix the issue?

Previously my domain & the server were located on the same shared hosting. But recently the hosting provider hiked up my bills x4 and I decided to switch. Still, my domain is based on the first shared hosting, but my server is located on another hosting provider. I only changed the nameservers to point to the new hosting provider.

Comment: Have you copied all your postfix settings to the new server? check `mail_allow_recipients` in your postfix config, do you see the domain whitelisted?

Comment: Hello @Riz - I'm not sure what you're referring to with mail_allow_recipients. I'm using shared hosting providers and I just copied all my files & databases from the previous host to the newer one.

Comment: All emails have this issue or just some? Also can you resolve the domain to which you are sending emails from your sever? Also what does `postconf -n` give you?

Comment: Also check your logs and check if your have changed the region too as you cannot use ses credentials created in one region in another region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me. I think I manage to find the solution, which of course was very simple:
When I changed the nameservers of my domain name I didn't move all the DNS records to the new hosting, because I thought that the old DNS records will be used. After a day or two Amazon revoked my DKIM status and send me an email stating that there are no DNS records to be found.

So I copied the DNS records to the new server and my status was returned. Now I'm sending emails again, so far (around 12-15 hours) without any problems.